# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Custom LoggingProvider filter in appsettings.json

Tags: c#, asp.net

In asp.net core it is possible to register the different logging providers:

```
services.AddLogging(builder => builder
            .AddConsole()
            .AddDebug();
```

Then configure inside appsetttings.json:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "Console": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Warning"
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

But how do I configure the log level for a custom logging provider:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider,MyLoggerProvider>
```

What should be added to appsettings.json and what should be done in code? I am guessing something like:

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "Console": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Warning"
             }
         }
         "?":{
             "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Debug"
             } 
         }
     }
 }
```

But what goes in "?" if indeed this is the correct approach?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ProviderAlias attribute on your CustomLoggerProvider class and add that Alias to appsettings.json file.

```
[ProviderAlias("MyLogger")]
  public class MyLoggerProvider



  "MyLogger":{
         "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug"
         } 
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, looks good. I haven't had a chance to try it out, but will do so when I get time.